# PHP CURL Parse multiple set-cookie headers using preg_match

Tags: php, regex, curl, preg-match

I'm using PHP/CURL to automate calls between 2 closely tied code igniter.

Code igniter is returning two `set-cookie` headers, one for a secure cookie with the real session data, one for insecure connections with an empty session...

```
Set-Cookie: overshare=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Thu, 17-Jun-2010 05:09:32 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: overshare=BdHJPVt...STsCxnMBj; path=/; secure
```

I've been trying to parse the secure cookie (both sites are on the same domain so if I get updated session information via CURL, I should update the clients cookie as if they made the call directly)

I'm currently using the following to parse the cookie:

```
preg_match('/Set-Cookie: (.*)\b/', $Head, $Cookies);
```

which gives me in `$Cookies`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Set-Cookie: overshare=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Thu, 17-Jun-2010 05:09:32 GMT; path
    [1] => overshare=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Thu, 17-Jun-2010 05:09:32 GMT; path
)
```

but this is only matching the first set-cookie header. My regex skills are poor - how can I match the second header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `$Head` is a single string containing all of the cookie headers, you're looking for [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all). [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg_match) stops after finding the first match.

With `preg_match_all()`, matched entire strings will be in `$Cookies[0]`. Your subpattern matches will be in `$Cookies[1]`.

```
$Head = <<<HEAD
Set-Cookie: overshare=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Thu, 17-Jun-2010 05:09:32 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: overshare=BdHJPVt...STsCxnMBj; path=/; secure
HEAD;

preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie: (.*)\b/', $Head, $Cookies);

print_r($Cookies);
```

yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Set-Cookie: overshare=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Thu, 17-Jun-2010 05:09:32 GMT; path
            [1] => Set-Cookie: overshare=BdHJPVt...STsCxnMBj; path=/; secure
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => overshare=a%3A0%3A%7B%7D; expires=Thu, 17-Jun-2010 05:09:32 GMT; path
            [1] => overshare=BdHJPVt...STsCxnMBj; path=/; secure
        )

)
```

Also, your wildcard `(.*)` is greedy by default, so it may consume both strings together if the headers aren't on separate lines. If so, try `(.*?)` to make it ungreedy.

Comment: Thank you - Especially for spotting the greedy match.

Comment: + for great explanation